# How would calculate an area coordinate on a flexible image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, responsive-design

Imagine a responsive app with image face tagging. You can drag an area, tag the person and it records the coordinates using (http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/)

But imagine the image get resized with css to adapt for the window size, the absolute coords don't fit anymore of course.

What would be a better strategy to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried getting the image width through jQuery? `$('.theimage').width()`

Comment: Still, imagine a 500px width pic with area starting at 20px 20px. Resizing the browser, the image becomes 200px width but the area coord recorded that were recorded previously are still 20px 20px and thus out of place. So getting the size with Jquery doesnt help here.

Comment: Would that make sense to interpret the coord based on the img original size and calculate a ratio based on the actual size, then adjust all the coordinates for each maps area?